# boost::regex_replace

Tags: c++, regex, boost, replace

Currently I have a problem with boost :: regex, I need to find the appropriate word և replace.  with the corresponding word. My code now looks like this.

```
std::string name = ptap;
std::string name_regex = "\\b" + name + "\\b"; 
boost::regex reg(name_regex);
checks_str = boost::regex_replace( checks_str, reg, alias_name );
```

There are words in the file that look like "ptap.power" because regex reads the dot as any character. The initial part of this word (ptap) changes, which I do not need.  How to fix this?

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem? What are `ptap`, `name` and `alias_name`  here?

Comment: "ptap" is a string it should be in quotes, like this:  std::string name = "ptap";

Comment: These are the names of the layers that make up a small part of a large project. If you find "ptap" in the text, you should replace it with the words alias_name.
If you come across the word "ptap.power" or another "." containing, that word remains the same. Thanks for the feedback)

Comment: Please provide a valid test case to see what problem you have got.

Comment: sorry i could not use boost with online compiler but my main code will be written in boost

Comment: I currently have a similar program #include <iostream>     `#include <regex>     #include <string>     int main()     {         std::string str = "ptap ptap.power";         std::string name = "ptap";         std::string rep = "pplug";         std::string regex_name = "\\b" + name + "\\b";         std::regex reg(regex_name);         str = std::regex_replace(str, reg, rep);         std::cout << str << std::endl;          return 0;     } ` 
 Which gives this result .    `pplug pplug.power` But I want to get this result.    `pplug ptap.power`

Comment: Ok, so you want to avoid replacing if there is a dot after the `ptap`? Then use `std::string regex_name = "\\b" + name + "\\b(?!\\.)";`

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to avoid replacing it - in cases where the point is before ptap? (for example power.ptap)

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent a match if there is a dot after a word:

```cpp
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "ptap ptap.power";
    std::string name = "ptap";
    std::string rep = "pplug";
    std::string regex_name = "\\b" + name + "\\b(?!\\.)";
    boost::regex reg(regex_name);
    str = boost::regex_replace(str, reg, rep);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6c0e0e1ae149fff).

The `(?!\.)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `.` char immediately to the right of the current location.

To avoid matching the keyword if there is a dot before, add a negative lookbehind:

```cpp
std::string regex_name = "\\b(?<!\\.)" + name + "\\b(?!\\.)";
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much for the previous answers. They worked very well in the previous cases but I have another problem.

Comment: @AzatZaroyan What is the problem?

Comment: What to do if in the previous case there is another character instead of a period, for example ptap:power, I need to replace it if it is ptap (it is not necessary at the beginning of the line, at the end or in the middle position), and in other cases if ptap: power, power:ptap,  ptap-power will not be replaced

Comment: @AzatZaroyan You are not providing exact pattern requirements. If you just provide examples, I can provide a pattern - e.g. `\b(?<![.:])ptap\b(?![.-]|:\s)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/023yKx/1)) - but it won't work once you come back and say "oh, I have more examples...). Please formulate the rules for matching, update the question and let me know,

Comment: I just brought the examples to make my question clearer, I need it not to be distorted after the `name` in case of any character if such a case is possible or replace only if there are no extra characters after the `name`.)